Name of a set operation (extension) and symbol

I speak French so that understanding the context (extension of a set in order to be able to solve an equation) is not a problem. My question is what is the name of this set operation and the name of the symbol.


You paste the whole paragraph without any highlighting and ask about one symbol. I can't really help.

In this context, I would not consider this a set operation.  The usage here is more along the lines of "$\Bbb N$ along with the unsolvable equation $x+5=2$ in $\Bbb N$ leads us to defining $\Bbb Z$ in order to have a solution."  As for the symbol itself... that is \hookrightarrow and more often occurs in my experience when defining an injective function.  The hookrightarrow and its meaning

One could consider the implication of the usual meaning of $\hookrightarrow$ along with this context that they are emphasizing that they intend to interpret $\Bbb N\subseteq \Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb R\subseteq \Bbb C$, as opposed to treating objects in $\Bbb N$ to not formally be elements in $\Bbb Z$ or similar and instead to have $\Bbb N$ be isomorphic to but otherwise distinct from a subset of $\Bbb Z$.

@pbb I apologize. See my update. Thank you for your comment.

@JMoravitz is right, it's \hookrightarrow, usually used for injection.
